# Paged blobs from azure storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage, pageable

I am curently trying to get a list of paged blobs from azure, but I don't really know how and I am kind of stuck. I have this method that is Pageable (it acces the blobs for a specific student, based on the id).

```
public Pageable<BlobItem> GetBlobsFromContainer(Guid studentId)
        {
            var containerClient = GetBlobContainerClient(studentId.ToString());
            return containerClient.GetBlobs();
        }
```

but I don't know how to use it in this direction. Curently it returns all the blobs existing  and I am hoping for a paged result, with 6 maybe 7 blobs per page. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.pageable-1?view=azure-dotnet) for the `Pageable` class you can see that this does not (yet) actually paginate the results but only retrieves **all** results  *for* pagination.

You should use the `Pageable<T>.AsPages()` to return a list of pages (of type `Page<T>`, have look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/pagination) on how to treat the result of your function

Comment: But is there a way to get only a few blobs from azure? Something like read 10 at a time, even if there are 100?

Comment: You could derive from the Pageable class and implement your own AsPages method that chunks the results into the size you want